# Include one PHP file into another

Tags: php

I need to include one PHP file into another. The PHP file that needs to be included sits in a separate directory though. This is how it is set up:

```
folder1/global-functions.php
folder1/folder2/functions.php
```

I need to include the 'global-functions.php' in the 'functions.php'

I tried:

```
<?php include("../global-functions.php"); ?>
```

But this will not work. It returns this error message:

> Warning: include(../global-functions.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/folder1/folder2/custom_functions.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../global-functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/folder1/folder2/custom_functions.php on line 2

Comment: you want to include your global-functions but in your code, you included just functions.php. ..i think you have to change it to <?php include("../global-functions.php"); ?>

Comment: I think you are trying wrong...<?php include("../global-functions.php"); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the file with an absolute path: something like this:

```
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder1/global-functions.php");?>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I get the sam error message as above.

Comment: Instead of using the $_server array I just typed in the full path and it seems to have worked.

Comment: @Nick The problem with typing the full path is that it might not won't work if you later copy your code to another server, since the path would be different. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should hold the absolute path to your web root folder (ie. public_html).

Comment: @w3d I tried it several times but it simply wont work. I have a feeling it is a wordpress issue. I am going to investigate further as little pieces on incomplete code annoy me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wordpress can have issues with the $_SERVER object, sometimes restricting access to it [http://wordpress.org/support/topic/_server-script-uri-query-string-etc-unable-to-retieve](example) . Unless something on your server changes it shouldn't matter if its hardcoded in...

Comment: @Coomie Thanks for the info. I am new to PHP but I have a feeling I can use the wordpress bloginfo function ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)) to make the code a little more dynamic. All my sites are run on wordpress so using that function will work on all my servers if I copy code over.

Comment: Good luck, Nick. If you need help with PHP check out www.php.net

Answer (score 0):

You are including functions.php in itself. Change functions.php to global-functions.php.

And just out of curiosity, why have different files for functions? Why not make classes and objects and make your life easier?

Comment: Sorry I had a copy + paste error there I was including the global-functions.php in not the functions.php.

As for your question, I am working with Thesis theme in WordpressMU. This means that there is a separate version of the theme with it's own functions.php file for each MU blog installation. There are a few common functions across all blog installs that I want to include in a global-functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your original include fails because... the relative path in your include is relative to the current directory, which in your case is not "folder1/folder2/". The current directory is likely to be the page from which you are serving your content.

You need to either use an absolute path (with the help of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as in @Coomie's answer) or change your include_path to include the location of your included files (but then you must not use a relative path, but you wouldn't need to anyway).