# include files from subdirectory which calls from another directory

Tags: php, include, include-path

I have a file here: public_html/wiki/index.php

Im calling these files:

```
<?php
include "../auth.php";
include "../header.php";
?>
```

However, my page looks like this:
[image]

If I paste the same file in `public_html/index.php` then it will look like this:
[image]

I think I've narrowed it down to my header.php file which is being called from `/wiki/` but header calls files from `../css..` and `../js` and so on.

How can this be adressed? I've looked at many posts already which tells me to define a global variable but it doesn't help me. Like so:

```
<?php //config file in root folder
define("ROOT", __DIR__ ."/");
?>
```

and then calling them with this:

```
<?php
include_once("../config.php");
include (ROOT ."auth.php");
include (ROOT ."header.php");
?>
```

How should I do this so I can get all my javascripts and the actual site with me in another folder?

Comment: Why assign what's already a PHP constant to another constant? `require_once realpath( __DIR__ . '/../auth.php' );` - and I'm pretty sure I've already seen a question very similar to this locked as being a duplicate today  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562839/php-include-a-php-file-within-another-php-file#comment45437168_28562839

Comment: As for the CSS and JS inside your header file, anything that's client-side can just be referenced to the document root `<script src="/js/something.js"> </script>` (note the leading **/**)

Comment: @CD001 realpath is the same as __dir__ after php 5.3 and ive already tried like this question says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074604/include-one-php-file-into-another it doesnt work

Comment: @CD001 however, you were right about the js thing. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: I WANTED THIS AS A COMMENT BUT DO NOT HAVE THE REP*

We have a different folder structure, but it is good practice to put your includes in one folder and from there link all the JS files (best practice is, place them in a pre-footer for speed) and then do

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/page-footer.php'; ?>
```

Just change the file name to suit you :) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

the problem was my include file didnt specify links as /js/file.js

i had them as js/file.js.

thanks @cd001